# maven build getting stuck at initial step

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea

When i try to perform maven build in intellij for Scala project its getting stuck. Even Maven clean is getting stuck after printing first line

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\bin\java.exe" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:56056,suspend=y,server=n -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\ak18191\Documents\projects\CCPA_Purge_framework\CCPA_purge_framework -Djansi.passthrough=true -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Users\ak18191\Citi\Citi_PROD_CAs_JKS\cacerts.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.1 Community Edition\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.1 Community Edition\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.1 Community Edition\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar" -javaagent:C:\Users\ak18191\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2023.2\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.1 Community Edition\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.7.0.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.1 Community Edition\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds.license;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.1 Community Edition\lib\idea_rt.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2023.2.1 clean
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:56056', transport: 'socket'
```

I am not sure what is the issue. How to debug what is the issue. please help

Comment: It looks like you are in remote debug mode. How are you running your app?

Comment: Your command has debugging parameters set in a mode where the program will not start until a debugger is actually listening (`-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:56056,suspend=y,server=n`).

Answer (score 0):

There was some issue with the maven installation. Its working fine after i install different version of intellij IDEA 2022.3